# Exercício: loop e for

Tags: javascript, algoritmo

> Execute uma função chamada `passandoPor` que imprime no console *"aqui eu tenho o valor de x"* onde `x` será o valor de `i` em cada iteração, para cada valor de 0 a 3.

O código que fiz foi esse abaixo! O final está errado com toda certeza e bem incompleto, mas de fato não sei o que fazer para rodar!

```
function passandoPor () {
  for (var i=0; i <2; i++) {
    console.log ("aqui eu tenho o valor de", i)
  }
}
```

O erro é esse:

> Sua solução não passou as provas
>   Resultados do teste:
>
> Imprimir passandoPor() deveria imprimir 'aqui eu tenho o valor de 0','aqui eu 
>   tenho o valor de 1','aqui eu tenho o valor de 2','aqui eu tenho o valor de 3'
>
> sua solução imprime o seguinte resultado:
>   'aqui eu tenho o valor de\naqui eu tenho o valor de\n' == 'aqui eu tenho o valor > de 0\naqui eu tenho o valor de 1\naqui eu tenho o valor de 2\

Comment: Você quer executar a função?

Comment: Isso! tá dando erro!

Comment: Qual erro você está recebendo? Clique em [edit] para editar adicionar a sua resposta e adicionar mais detalhes, como o erro que você diz estar ocorrendo.

Comment: Pronto, editei!

Comment: O problema é na condição de iteração do `for`, seu laço itera enquanto `i` for menor que 2. Você tem que o fazer iterar enquanto `i` for menor ou igual a 3. Leia [Instrução for](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Comment: Ok! Vou tentar! Muito obrigada!

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 4):

Não sei de onde vem o enunciado, mas ele não é bom, eu repensaria se vale a pena continuar com esta fonte de estudo. Por exemplo ele falar em `x`e mandar a variável do laço ser `i`. Talvez ele queira que crie uma variável `x` que seja exatamente o valor de `i`, mas para que? Talvez queira que use `x` e não `i`, mas não faz sentido dentro do escrito. E na verdade um enunciado não deveria dar nomes para variáveis, parte do aprendizado deveria ser a pessoa aprender nomear bem por conta própria.

Bom, depois da edição percebemos que o problema nem era o enunciado era no que foi postado aqui  (aparentemente minha interpretação estava correta), é preciso cuidado com o que pergunta, perguntar é bem mais fácil que programar, se errar nisto complica. O site está informando erros que não podiam acontecer no código postado aqui, então talvez o que foi postado aqui seja diferente do que postou lá, fica mais complicado ainda ajudar, eu tentei.

Apesar da ambiguidade eu vou interpretar que deve imprimir de 0 à 3, inclusive. O seu código está imprimindo de 0 à 2 exclusive (o 2 nem imprime). Para ir até o 3 deve usar este número e não 2 como foi usado (isto não é questão de saber programar), e para ser inclusivo e não exclusivo deve usar o `<=` (menor ou igual) e não o `<` (menor) (isto é matemática e não programação).

Não tinha outros erros, nenhum de programação. E não está dando erro algum no código, só não está dando o resultado esperado e o site que está usando para corrigir isto está negando esse resultado, precisa entender que o código não tem erro, o algoritmo é que não faz o pretendido, é uma lógica equivocada, sem entender isso terá dificuldades (e terá outras se não conseguir entender que este site não é o processo de execução normal de um código.

Se ainda continuar com o erro é porque o enunciado mal feito quer dizer outra coisa, por exemplo pode ser que deva usar `<` porque o 3 é exclusivo.

Note que eu melhorei algumas coisas no código que não fazem dar erro ou resultado ruim, mas é bom ir aprendendo.

A chama do da função pode não ser necessária no site que está usando, que não sabemos qual é e por isso nem podemos ajudar mais que isto. Uma leitura minuciosa em [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101) ajudaria fazer melhores perguntas e se preparar melhor para programar.

```js
function passandoPor() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) console.log("aqui eu tenho o valor de", i);
}
passandoPor();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/LoopInclusive.js).

Comment: Acho interessante colocar o corpo do `for` entre blocos chaveados ao invés de um bloco _inline_, para facilitar o entendimento do que está acontecendo ali. Noções de programação ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: Eu acho o oposto, dá até pra falar sobre isso (o que você já fez) , mas mostrar que não tem uma só forma de fazer e a pessoa entender em vez de sempre fazer igual pra mim ensina mais. Não está entrando um conceito novo mas sim uma sintaxe diferente da exata mesma coisa.

Comment: _"o que você já fez"_ - onde e o que eu fiz? :P

Comment: Falou que pode usar as chaves também.

Comment: Muito obrigada pela atenção de todos vocês.

Comment: O site é bem complicadinho mesmo, não funciona de jeito nenhum! Mas de todo modo, muito obrigada mesmo pela atenção de vocês!

Answer (score 4):

Boa tarde!

Segue a solução abaixo, conforme solicitado.

```js
function passandoPor() {
  for(var i = 0; i <=3; i++) {
    var x = i;
   console.log("aqui eu tenho o valor de " + x);
}
}
```

Qualquer dúvida estou à disposição!

Comment: Obrigada!!! Ajudou muitooo!!

Answer (score 2):

Estou fazendo esse mesmo exercício e ele tem algumas peculiaridades no momento da correção que não foram ensinados:

```
function passandoPor() {
 var frase = "aqui eu tenho o valor de ";
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      console.log(frase.concat(i));
  }
}
```

Comment: Vcs me ajudaram muito! Obrigada msm!!  Tentei de tudo e nada dava certo!

Answer (score 2):

Como disseram ali em cima, achei estranho esse lance do x e do i, mas uma forma bem bacana que dá pra fazer é controlar as duas variaveis pelo for, então o código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```js
function passandoPor() {
    for(var i = 0, x = 0; i <=3; i++, x++) {
     console.log("aqui eu tenho o valor de " + x);
  }
}

passandoPor()
```

Comment: Vale ressaltar que ainda continua não fazendo muito sentido pois o x e o i estão fazendo a mesma coisa...

Answer (score 1):

A fonte dessas perguntas trata-se de um site de nivelamento, que está prospectando candidatos que almejam bolsas de estudo, e lá, é preciso que a função seja chamada exatamente do jeito que eles querem, mesmo existindo várias formas e executar essa função. Aqui está a forma correta para a execução rodar:

```
function passandoPor() {
for(var i=0; i<4; i++) {
console.log(‘aqui eu tenho o valor de’ + “ “ + i);
}
}
```

Nas dicas há uma informação que é necessário concatenar!

Answer (score 1):

Você deve concatenar usando + e não vírgula

```
function passandoPor () {
  for (var i=0; i <4; i++) {
    console.log ("aqui eu tenho o valor de" +  i)
  }
}
```